# Need help adding method to Eigen library through EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN

Tags: c++, templates, sparse-matrix, eigen3

I am trying to integrate the Eigen library with an existing codebase, so I want to add a new multiplication method which is just a copy of the existing operator *. I keep getting the error: error: 'Eigen::MatrixXf' has no member named 'multiply' after Ive written it.

I want to add the method multiply to Eigen::Matrix as just the * operator via the following code:

```
    template <typename OtherDerived>
    inline PlainObject multiply(const MatrixBase<OtherDerived>& other)
    {
        return *this * other;
    }
```

but I keep getting the error:
error: 'Eigen::MatrixXf' has no member named 'multiply'

EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN is set as the file that contains the new method

I want to know what I'm doing wrong and how to solve it, the code Im running is just a multiplication

```
vec_out = mat1 * vec1;
```

and I want

```
vec_out = mat1.multiply(vec1);
```

to do the same thing.

where

```
vec_out is a Eigen::VectorXf
mat1    is a Eigen::MatrixXf
vec1    is a Eigen::VectorXf
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Note I cannot change our library to use * instead of multiply() as that would break compatibility to a significant amount of other code.

Comment: For a [mre] please also provide a (minimal) main cpp file and the command line arguments you are passing to the compiler. Are you sure the plugin got included? You need to have the `EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN` defined before any Eigen header is included -- ideally via the command-line. And this should be done for all compilation units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, I figured it out, somewhere in my test set I switched to sparse matrices instead of full matrices, all the newly added methods work with full matrices.